# Connection reset on accessing admin pages

Tags: users

I've seen this error in several places online, but haven't really found a solution yet. I developed a site using the LAMP stack on Ubuntu, then installed a WAMP server in Win7. I copied the files, and imported the database. I can access normal pages fine (clean urls enabled), but whenever I access site/admin/*, I get a `This webpage is not available The connection to www.site.com was interrupted.` error.

I've already cleared the cache tables, and haven't yet found any other troubleshooting tips.

Thanks for the help

EDIT: The site is also on a vhost. I can run apps like phpmyadmin with no problems.

Comment: Do you get an entry on the apache logs for visiting any of those pages?

Comment: I don't supposed it could be related to [this old chestnut](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32642)?

Comment: There was no entry at all on either the access or error logs. I tried increasing the max_allowed_packet to 4m, with no change.