# In D7, VBO gives Ajax error

Tags: views

I am using Views to create a content view page. Whenever I try to add the VBO pull-down menu with the Delete all checked option, Views gives me a popup window with the following error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   /admin/structure/views/view/find_content_new/preview/page/ajax
>   StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) ResponseText:
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away in variable_set() (line 972 of
>   /usr/local/www/drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc).

I've searched around and couldn't find much on this error. I reinstalled Drupal, then Views and VBO. Still getting the error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking at the actual page display, or the views preview?

Comment: @DavidThomas this error shows up in the Views admin page /admin/structure/views/view/find_content_new/edit, when I save the adding of the VBO Operations (delete & publish) field to the View, and whenever I subsequently return to the edit page.

Comment: @DavidThomas interestingly enough I just realized that it only gives me the error when I add VBO to the find content page. I've added VBO to other views now and it works fine...

Comment: I'm using the latest DEV version. The problem only occurs when using the Views preview screen.

Comment: I've run into this and increasing your MYSQL max packet size kind of helps usually ... oh wait, that was with views_data_export .... probably related, try anyways.

Comment: Yes, that works. The problem also went away when I updated Drupal core last month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nasty database error when adding any type of content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/nasty-database-error-when-adding-any-type-of-content)