# Fatal PHP error on Drupal 7 with IIS

Tags: database, iis

Logging as Admin user on Drupal 7 website stored on an IIS machine, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' 
in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\database\database.inc:2139  
Stack trace: 
#0 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\database\database.inc(2139): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1     E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\database\database.inc(664): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) 
#2 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\database\database.inc(2318): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array) 
#3 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array) 
#4 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...') 
#5 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\bootstrap.inc(420): lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...') 
#6 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\bootstrap.inc(442): DrupalCacheArray->set(Array) 
#7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray->__destruct() 
#8 {main} thrown inE:\inetpub\wwwroot\teams\includes\database\database.inc on line 2139
```

Any idea on how do I debug those statements? And how do I release locks?

Comment: I'd be 99.999% certain it's for the same reason as this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/nasty-database-error-when-adding-any-type-of-content. Since this is IIS I'm not totally sure though. I think the config file is my.ini (not my.cnf) under Windows, again not sure

Comment: Yeah, that PDO error on a cache related query == problem with max_allowed_packet.

Comment: Yes @clive, it was for the same reason. The only difference was that we needed to boot the machine after changing the parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, setting maximum allowed packet size in MySQL worked like charm. To solve, we've went to the `[mysqld]` section of `my.ini` and added the following:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

then restarted the Windows server machine in order to restart MySQL.

The only difference in **IIS** is that the machine required a boot.

Comment: You could also run `net stop mysql`, paused 15 seconds, and `net start mysql` in the event you can't restart the Windows server.