# WSOD when enabling a module

Tags: wsod

Enabling the *Comment* module, I get WSOD everywhere.

Suspecting insufficient memory, I have added to sites/default/default.settings.php the following statement :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

After stopping/relaunching the *MAMP* servers, under *phpMyAdmin* I emptyed every table in the DB, then reimported the latest *Backup & Migrate* backup,

then trying again to enable *Comment* : WSOD :-(

The log file is pretty cryptic to me :

```
[25-Nov-2014 19:50:46 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/database/database.inc:2171
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/database/database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
#2 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/database/database.inc(2350): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array)
#3 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array)
#4 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...')
#5 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/bootstrap.inc(424): lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...')
#6 /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/bootstrap.inc(446): DrupalCacheArray->set(Array)
#7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray- in /Users/Gil/Documents/MAMP/des_gens_f/includes/database/database.inc on line 2171
```

I've edited the Applications/MAMP/Library/support-files/my-*.cnf files (there are five, ignoring the one that applies, I deited each one). Editing the default `max_allowed_packet = 1M` (thanks Clive for the links), I tried successively `16M`, `32M`, `64M`, `128M`, `256M` and `512M`. Still getting the same log :-(

It's my first Drupal project. Any track from someone more MySQL/PHP savvy than I ? Thanks.

Comment: Also see... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72570/general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away in case the first one doesn't help

Comment: It looks like my error was deleting all tables under _phpMyAdmin_. I just learnt that a _BackUp & Migrate_ backup **doesn't** record all the tables, as I thought.

Comment: I made two mistakes.

Comment: 1) I edited I edited _my-small.cnf_, _my-medium.cnf_, etc. which are only example files. So, I created _Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf_
`[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 64M`

Comment: 2) I edited _Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini_, but the right one is _Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini_. Adding `memory_limit = 128M`, everything is ok :-)