# Why can I not add new content after updating some module?

Tags: nodes

After module update, I don't remember which one, I can't add a new content.

Lately it keeps displaying this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 15506721 bytes) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/cache.inc on line
>   454

I've modified the file .htacces settings.php, increasing the value of `memory_limit` from `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` to `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');`

But this other error returns:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc:2171
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc(2171):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc(683):
>   DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc(2350):
>   DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array) #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/lock.inc(167):
>   db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array) #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/lock.inc(146):
>   lock_may_be_available('theme_registry:...') #5
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/theme.inc(449):
>   lock_acquire('theme_registry:...') #6
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc(455):
>   ThemeRegistry->set(Array) #7 [inte in
>   /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/includes/database/database.inc
>   on line 2171

And then this other one:

> /var/www/vhosts/liceoguaccibn.it/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter_boolean_operator.inc
>   on line 90

Any suggestion?

**Note**: It 's true I decreased memory, but then I reported to 256M and beyond that I have cleared the cache, but without success.
Surely it is in some forms, but how do I find them?

Comment: it was a memory_limit error and you decreased allowed memory size? why did you do that? at first return your memory limit to 256MB then disable some modules and then perform cleaning caches

Comment: It 's true I decreased memory, but then I reported to 256M and beyond that I have cleared the cache, but without success.
Surely it is in some forms, but how do I find them

Comment: Try disabling modules bt groups to speed process up. You do it modifying the systen table. Also, if you have devel installed hack temporary the drupal_get_form adding dd($$form_id) to print out which forms are being processed. Last printed form is your man.

Comment: I thank you for the answer, but I have not figured out how to do what you suggested, you could tell me step by step the various operations?
As I understand the problem is placed in the folder with the jQuery library         thank's

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/32642/1908).