# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away:

Tags: 8, database

After entering some custom fields, I went to /content and now I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.

I've tried the following with no success:

- Cleared cache (via drush)
- Rebuilt Docker Container with increase in  PHP config’s `max_allowed_packet` (recommended by several posts online).
- Restart `container/docker`.

*If I connect to another database, I don't see the error.*
Database connection was fine, this error happened after making changes to fields in Drupal Admin UI. The other answers seem to be for issues connecting to SQL, I have no such issues. Just specefic to the contents of a single database.

Here is the complete error:

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
>    Original
>
> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: CREATE TABLE {cache_default} ( `cid` VARCHAR(255) BINARY CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.', `data` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.', `expire` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or -1 for never.', `created` DECIMAL(14, 3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A timestamp with millisecond precision indicating when the cache entry was created.', `serialized` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).', `tags` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Space-separated list of cache tags for this entry.', `checksum` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The tag invalidation checksum when this entry was saved.', PRIMARY KEY (`cid`), INDEX `expire` (`expire`), INDEX `created` (`created`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COMMENT 'Storage for the cache API.'; Array ( ) in Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet() (line 211 of /var/www/html/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php).
>
> Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet('views_data', Array) (Line: 259)
>       Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 162)
>       Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
>       Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
>       Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
>       Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
>       Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
>       Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 147)
>       views_theme(Array, 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 447)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'views', 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 334)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 86)
>       Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 67)
>       Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:seven', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 253)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 142)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 437)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object, 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
>       Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object, 'install_page', Array) (Line: 1005)
>       install_display_output(Array, Array) (Line: 156)
>       install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
>
> Additional
>
> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: CREATE TABLE {cache_default} ( `cid` VARCHAR(255) BINARY CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.', `data` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.', `expire` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or -1 for never.', `created` DECIMAL(14, 3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A timestamp with millisecond precision indicating when the cache entry was created.', `serialized` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).', `tags` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Space-separated list of cache tags for this entry.', `checksum` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The tag invalidation checksum when this entry was saved.', PRIMARY KEY (`cid`), INDEX `expire` (`expire`), INDEX `created` (`created`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COMMENT 'Storage for the cache API.'; Array ( ) in Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet() (line 211 of /var/www/html/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php).
>
> Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet('views_data:block_content', Array) (Line: 178)
>       Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
>       Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
>       Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
>       Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
>       Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
>       Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 147)
>       views_theme(Array, 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 447)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'views', 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 334)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 86)
>       Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 67)
>       Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:seven', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 253)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 142)
>       Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 437)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
>       Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 1005)
>       install_display_output(Array, Array, Array) (Line: 260)
>       _drupal_log_error(Array, 1) (Line: 600)
>       _drupal_exception_handler(Object)

Comment: I think `MySQL server has gone away` mean that your Mysql server not running, did you try `drush sql-cli` to check if you can connect to mysql .

Comment: @berramou drush sql-cli connects and if I swap databases (by changing name in settings.php) it works, so it is connecting.

Comment: You added the create table information... does the SQL user you are connecting with have the rights to create tables?  You can also test this by trying to create a temporary table using the drush sql-cli command line (just a wrapper for mysql that uses drupal id/password).  You might also check the mysql logs for more error info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question:

[Database general error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/database-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away?rq=1)

Basically, you need to increase the MySQL max_allowed_packet setting.  There is an option as well to compress cached data if you can't.

http://drupal.org/node/1281408

Comment: I increased max_allowed_packet but it had no effect.

Comment: I examined my SQL and found: Aborted connection 11 to db:  (Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes)
I believe I need to increase max_allowed_packet in my SQL not my PHP.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks

Comment: My issue was importing a fairly large database into Drupal via Drush cmd: 
$  vendor/drush/drush/drush sqlc < import.sql   and updating the MYSQL max_allowed_packet to 10 times the amount worked!

Comment: Just want to add that I was able to fix this error by simply rebooting the Linux webserver that the site was on. Don't forget to try the easy stuff first before messing with a bunch of settings etc.